# How to Access the UIViewController class/className that presents a Modal View?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller

Just a simple question

Currently i present a modal view like this:

```
+ (void)showModalController:(id)ContentController InViewController:(UIViewController*)vc withFrame:(CGRect)rect{

UINavigationController *modalViewNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:ContentController];
modalViewNavController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
modalViewNavController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;

[vc presentModalViewController:modalViewNavController animated:YES];

//it's important to do this after presentModalViewController
modalViewNavController.view.superview.frame = rect;

//self.view assumes the base view is doing the launching, if not you might need self.view.superview.center etc.
modalViewNavController.view.superview.center = vc.view.center;

[modalViewNavController release];
```

}

I pass the values of the UIViewController Content that it will be presented, at a custom modal size. I also pass the values of the UIViewController where the modal it will be presented.

In terms of code, i want to know the "vc" name at the content class, if it's possible to do so.

**EDIT**

Lets say i have 2 classes, one is called **DetailViewController** where the modal will be presented. And the other one is called **ModalContentViewController**.

I want to know at the **ModalContentViewController** class (when the view appears, or is loaded) the name of the **DetailViewController**.

Any ideas?

PD: Currently Using...

XCode 4.4.1
iPad Simulator iOS5.1
iOS5.1

Comment: Could you clean up your question a little? I'm confused as to whether you're getting the name of the of the content controller or the presenting view controller. Also, you should consider two improvements: declare `ContentController` as a `UIViewController *` instead of `id`. This ensures that if you try to pass something that isn't a `UIViewController` (subclass) that you'll get a warning, which is good because the `initWithRootVC` method requires a view controller.

Comment: Second, you might consider making this method a category on `UIViewController`, which you can do by going to file > new file > obj-c category > category on `UIViewController`. Then, add this method as an instance method on `UIViewController`. This is a more natural way of writing the method, rather than passing in the view controller to present it from (`InViewController:`)

Comment: Thanks MaxGabriel,
I will make the change and read a little about categories

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look for the `UIViewController` property `presentingViewController`. Here's a quote from the docs:

> If the view controller that received this message is presented by
>   another view controller, this property holds the view controller that
>   is presenting it. If the view controller is not presented, but one of
>   its ancestors is being presented, this property holds the view
>   controller presenting the nearest ancestor. If neither the view
>   controller nor any of its ancestors are being presented, this property
>   holds nil.

So you could use that property to get the presenting VC's name.

Comment: Thanks!, with the ancestor i could access the viewcontroller.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `NSStringFromClass(vc.class)` to get the class name as an `NSString`.

Comment: Hi MaxGabriel,

I know how to access the classname, but i cant access the DetailViewController (where it is presented) at the ModalViewController Class (Content of the ModalView). i posted an example at the question to be more clear.